# Extra Argument 'forReadingWithData" in call in Xcode SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

It seems like they have updated the process for this. For whatever reason it doesn't work in the new version of Xcode. The archiver line is the line with the error

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks")

    var sceneData: AnyObject? = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!)
    var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift will sometimes report an error that doesn't have anything to do with the real issue. In this case, the argument for `NSKeyedUnarchiver:forReadingWithData` should be an `NSData` object not an `AnyObject?`. The following will resolve the issue

```
if let sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!) as? NSData {
    var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
}
```

Comment: Optional binding would a better choice: `if let sceneData = sceneData { ...`, or more concisely: `if let sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path) as? NSData { ...`